# How to use unsupervised classification to "test" labels of supervised classification

Tags: classification

If i know $k$ labels i can do a supervised classification.

Have any sense perform also unsupervised classification and made a prediction table to understand if the new $k$ label of unsupervised are the same initial label?

If the answer is no ,what can i deduce?

Comment: You have to find a distance and a merging criterion for your unsupervised classification that would yield about the same results as your supervised classification. So it would make sense if you manage to have compatible methods of (un)surpervised classification.